# How to SAXParse a website?

Tags: java, android, parsing, xml-parsing, saxparser

I'm new to Android development. I've been following a book to learn: Head First Android Development - Jonathan Simon. I came across a SAXParser implementation although the code seems outdated and the tutorials online are either also outdated or do not show how to parse from a website.

SAXParser.java

```
    package com.example.saxparser;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;

    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class SAXParser extends DefaultHandler {
private String url = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";
private boolean inTitle = false;
private boolean inDescription = false;
private boolean inItem = false;
private String title = null;
private StringBuffer description = new StringBuffer();

public void processFeed() {
    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory =
                SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(this);
        InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
        reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public void startElements(String url, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.startsWith("to")) { inItem = true; }
    else if (inItem) {
        if (localName.equals("from")) { inTitle = true; }
        else { inTitle = false; }

        if (localName.equals("heading")) { inDescription = true; }
        else { inDescription = false; }
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    String chars = new String(ch).substring(start, start + length);
    if (inTitle && title == null) { title = chars; }
    if (inDescription) { description.append(chars); }
}

public String getTitle() { return title; }
public StringBuffer getDescription() { return description; }
 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.saxparser;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SAXParser handler = new SAXParser();
    handler.processFeed();

    resetDisplay(handler.getTitle(), handler.getDescription());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void resetDisplay(String title, StringBuffer stringBuffer) {
    TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
    titleView.setText(title);
    TextView descriptionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
    descriptionView.setText(stringBuffer);
}

}
```

Comment: Like any other XML document. That said, use jsoup or similar less-restrictive parser, lots easier. It's trickier when the website builds its DOM dynamically, which happens a lot.

Comment: Oh my this is crazy/overkill,  try http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new in the Android development world, so far I know SAX to work as for XML files parsers but I am not sure if you can parse an entire HTML. Bear in mind that although HTML it is a subset of SGML (and so it can be thought to be parsed with the same methods in SAX), it can be tricky (in fact XML can be considered a cousin to HTML and a nephew to SGML). You may find yourself getting into trouble regarding dynamically load stuff (as Dave Newton said). Maybe if you explain a little more your objective we all can give you a more detail explanation/advice (or go deeper with what Pity proposed), for instance... is the website that hosts what you want to parse offering an XML API? I guess it doesn't because you thought about parsing the HTML instead of parsing an XML API response. Give us more information, please.